# Why does ERC20 balanceof() use constant?

Tags: constants, state, solidity

The ERC20 token standard specifies `balanceof()` with a `constant`:

```cpp
function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}
```

But the function doesn't change the state of anything anyway. So what is the sense of **constant** here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions marked with the constant modifier do 2 things.

- Any attempts to change state in the function will not be written to the chain.
- Calls from a client will not use gas, unless called from another non-constant function.

Specifying this in the ERC20 standard just ensures you're following those rules. A client using the token should not have to unexpectedly pay for gas consumed just to get balance information.

Comment: Thanks, the no gas argument makes really sense here